# Customizing the Scroll View of a Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have an issue with the scroll of my table. When I scroll down my table, a button that I have above the table keeps at the same position an remains visible, what I need is that the button will disappear while I scroll down my table.

This is my code:

```
  @implementation Mis_Servicios


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self SetTopBarStyle];
    self.title = @"Mis servicios";
    barButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Editar"
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        Cell_Detalles *cell = nil;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell_registro";
        cell =(Cell_Detalles *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell_Detalles_7" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (Cell_Detalles *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

        cell.bt_preguntas.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
        cell.bt_preguntas.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x259026);
        [cell.bt_preguntas setTitle:@"Alta de servicios" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.bt_preguntas setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.bt_preguntas addTarget:self action:@selector(goAltas) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        NSLog(@"%f / %f",self.tableView.contentOffset.y, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height);

        if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y == self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height){
            if (pagenumber < pages) {
                ++pagenumber;
                [self ObtenerDatos];
            }

        }

    }
```

This is the button above the table: [cell.bt_preguntas setTitle:@"Alta de servicios" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

And this is an image of how does this screen looks like, I'm using Storyboard and Xib's for the Table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how section headers work on a plain style table view. See the Contacts tab of the Phone app for a good example.

If you only have the one button and you want it at the top of the table view and you want it to scroll as the table view is scrolled, then instead of implementing `viewForHeaderInSection`, you should set your button view as the table view's `tableHeaderView`.

Add the following code to your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell_Detalles_7" owner:self options:nil];
Cell_Detalles *cell = (Cell_Detalles *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

cell.bt_preguntas.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
cell.bt_preguntas.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x259026);
[cell.bt_preguntas setTitle:@"Alta de servicios" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.bt_preguntas setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.bt_preguntas addTarget:self action:@selector(goAltas) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = cell;
```

And remove your entire `viewForHeaderInSection` method.

Comment: Can you show me an example please? Sorry but I'm novice at objective C and I've never did that.